# Prevent loss of context for 'this' variable in a function passed as a parameter

Tags: javascript, function, parameters, this, typeerror

**Question**

How can I prevent the loss of context for `this` variable inside a function passed as a parameter?

**Simple Example, also in [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pfuge19h/)**

```
var a = {
    start: function() {
        b.start( this.process );
    },

    process: function( justAParameter ) {
        justAParameter += ' of multiple contexts!'

        this.finish( justAParameter );
    },

    finish: function( finishParameter ) {
        console.log( finishParameter );
    }
}

var b = {
    start: function( justAFunction ) {
        justAFunction( 'Hello world' )
    }
}

a.start();
```

**Expected Output**

`Hello world of multiple contexts!`

**Received Output**

`TypeError: this.finish is not a function`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `bind` to bind the value of `this` to the `process()` method when it's referenced as an argument

```
start: function() {
    b.start( this.process.bind(this) );
},
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/21cL0dgd/1/)